# Wait until a mutex is created in Python (win32)

Tags: python, winapi, mutex

I am using the **win32event** Python module to interact with a Mutex created in another program (C# based)

My code opens a mutex and then waits on it:

```
hWait = win32event.OpenMutex(win32con.MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, False, "mutexname")
win32event.WaitForSingleObject(hWait, 20000)
```

The problem with this code is that it fails in case the mutex is not yet created (for example if the python program attempts to open the mutex before the C# program creates it).

How can i block until a mutex was created? is there any Python or library method that allows this?

Comment: You may use the CreateMutex API, which is able to just "open" an existing mutex, or really create it if it doesn't exist, yet. But that may require cooperation from the C# side, which may not have ownership at 'creation' if you created it first. Another solution: loop while the mutext doesn't exist (with a Sleep in the loop)

Comment: current pywin32 win32con module has no constant called MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS

Comment: Do you need to use the win32 event mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

Note that when using `win32event.WaitForSingleObject`, rather than specifying some arbitrary but long enough time to wait for (20000), it's also possible to simply use `win32event.INFINITE` to block indefinitely until an event happens, as in:

```
win32event.WaitForSingleObject(waitable, win32event.INFINITE)
```

This can be useful for example when you need to tell code in another thread that the mutex opened.

Since waiting for the mutex fails if it's not yet created, we instead create an event to trigger when the mutex is opened.

```
mutex_open = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
```

Then start a thread that waits for the event:

```
def wait_for_opening(open_evt):
   win32event.WaitForSingleObject(open_evt, win32event.INFINITE)
   print("Got notified that mutex is now open.")

waiter = threading.Thread(target=wait_for_opening, args=(mutex_open,))
waiter.start()
```

To simulate the other program, start another thread that will create the mutex, after a while:

```
def delayed_create():
   time.sleep(1)
   m = CreateMutex(None, True, u"mutexname")

creator = threading.Thread(target=delayed_create)
creator.start()
```

Finally, run the loop that waits until the mutex opens, and sets the event after that.

```
while True:

   try:
      hWait = win32event.OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, False, "mutexname")
   except pywintypes.error:
      pass
   else:
      win32event.SetEvent(mutex_open)
      break
```

Note the `setEvent`call.

So, when running the code, after a while, the `waiter` thread gets notified that the mutex is now open.

Comment: That's a bad answer. If the mutex is not yet created, the OpenMutex call will fail!

Comment: Well yes, it answers the "how can I block until" part that you asked for, but does not solve the whole problem you have. I've reduced the answer to just giving the info on how to block indefinitely.

Comment: Well no, you CAN'T wait on a mutex if you FAILED to open it. Did you notice the "is created" after the "until" part? You really should delete this answer.

Comment: .. or expand it to illustrate the point and provide a full answer rather than just an informative contribution. Done.

Answer (score 0):

As also pointed out by @manuell (in comments), the simple solution is to loop until the mutex is created, silently catching the error that is raised when the mutex does not yet exist:

```
while True:

   try:
      hWait = win32event.OpenMutex(MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, False, "mutexname")
   except pywintypes.error:
      pass
   else:
      break
```

Depending on the specifics of your case, you may for example want to explicitly sleep a bit inside the loop, put the waiting loop in a separate thread, or turn it into a generator or coroutine, or use it to trigger a win32 event to run something in another already-running thread (see my other answer on how to wait for an event until it happens).